# Button in tab fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs, imagebutton

I was following tutorials on how to make Tabs using fragments.
each tab has this in the java files:

> public class rdfri extends Fragment {

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
   return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.rdfri, container, false);
}
```

> }

I would like to try and get a imageButton in the fragment. I figured image bottons work with this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rdmon);
```

> ImageButton rainbowbook = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

```
    rainbowbook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = Intent(rdmon.this, RainbowBookActivity.class);
            rdmon.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

> }

So how would I go about getting the button code in the fragment code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the button code in the overridden `onActivityCreated` method in your fragment class.

```
@Override 
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);   
    ImageButton rainbowbook = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    rainbowbook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        Intent myIntent = Intent(rdmon.this, RainbowBookActivity.class); 
        rdmon.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
       } 
    }); 
}
```

This assumes of course that your imagebutton is contained in your fragment layout.

Comment: so I just add that straight under:
       return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.rdmon, container, false);
    }

Comment: Not as part of the `onCreateView` method... a new method, but still in the fragment class.

Comment: I then get the 2 errors:
Description Resource Path Location Type
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type rdmon rdmon.java 
\

Description Resource Path Location Type
The method Intent(rdmon, Class<RainbowBookActivity>) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} rdmon.java

Comment: if I follow the quick fix that eclipse gives the the activity FC while running it on the phone.